# How To Design A Disassociation In A Rest API

Tags: rest

I have a question about how to properly design a REST interface that associates and disassociates resources. I have `rooms` that represent rooms in a home and `things` that represent things in a room. Users add rooms to their home by POSTing to `/rooms` and create 'things' by POSTing to `/things`. Great. We've got rooms and things and whatnot. Question is, how do I associate and disassociate these things?

Options, as far as I can tell:

Option 1 - `PUT` array of `things` to the `rooms` resource. To disassociate, PUT new array to the `rooms` resource with one less `thingId`

Option 2 - `POST` to `/rooms/:roomId/thing_associations`. Return resource association identifiers to be used to `DELETE` via `/rooms/:roomId/thing_associations/:associationId`. This would be analogous to a join table.

Option 3 - `POST` to `/rooms/:roomId/devices/:deviceId` to create the association. `DELETE` to `/rooms/:roomId/devices/:deviceId` to destroy the association. I personally hate this option as it creates tension in my brain :-|

Would love your thoughts. Anything I haven't considered? Probably.

Thanks!

Comment: Do your things make sense alone, i.e. without being inside a room?

Comment: Good questions. Yes things make sense alone. No, things can't be in two rooms at once.

Answer (score 0):

Can a thing be in two rooms at once? If not I would go with option 1.

GET - /rooms/ 
List of rooms

GET - /rooms/${room_id}
Room details

POST- /rooms/${room_id}
Add or update a room

DELETE - /rooms/${room_id}
Delete a room

GET - /rooms/${room_id}/things/
Lists of thing ids in ${room_id}

GET - /rooms/${room_id}/things/${thing_id}
Details of ${thing_id}

POST - /rooms/${room_id}/things/${thing_id}
Add or update $thing_id

DELETE - /rooms/${room_id}/things/${thing_id}
Remove $thing_id

etc...